# Meteor LTI Auth, data from Iron Router server route to client?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, lti

Am working on LTI Tool Provider, I have implemented an [LTI auth package](https://github.com/DavidSichau/meteor-lti-auth) and am successfully able to get two (..one?) legged OAuth working aka match the signatures and we're all good to redirect, except one important thing.

What I want to be able to do, is

- If this user doesnt exist, create it and log in
- If the user exists, log our user in

Right now I have no way of actually determining my user once I redirect to a client route.

The LTI Consumer points to my Iron Router server route that looks something like:

```
Router.route('/lti', { where: 'server' }).post(function() {
    provider.valid_request(request, function(error, valid) {
        if (valid) {
            this.response.writeHead(302, { Location: '/' });
        } else {
            this.response.writeHead(403);
        }
    });
    return this.response.end();
});
```

Are there any packages I can use to get this working simply? Can I use something like accounts-base? Do I need to implement my own logic?

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by implementing a single-use authentication token system, handled by a custom login handler using `accounts-base` and the `Accounts.registerLoginHandler` method.

Rough auth flow overview:

**LTI Route (server)**

1. If authenticated, create a new account/update the old one
2. Insert a token + timestamp object into a collection.
3. Redirect to an authentication route, passing  our token as a parameter

**Auth route (client)**

1. Check if our user is logged in. If so, redirect to our home route

   - If a token has been provided and it exists, mark it used. As we have no way of checking for a user in a server route, if a user has a session, closed and opens the link through the LMS again, we need to deal with our excess tokens.
2. If our user is not logged in, check for a token. If it exists, pass it to a custom authentication via `Accounts.callLoginMethod`
3. Our custom login handler validates our token. If legitimate, consume the token and log the user in.

My code is messy, but when I refactor I'll probably open source it as a Meteor package.